# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1 + x^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I want to evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1 + x^2}$$

by the residue theorem.

This function is not even, so I can not use the semi-circle approach.

I was trying to integrate over the triangle $T= \{(0,0),(T,0),(T,T)\}$ and then take the limit as $T\to\infty$ but I had no luck with the integrals.

I parametrize each edge of the triangle and I know that the function is analytic on T and the contour integral is 0. I dont know how to deal with the remaining integrals over the sides of T.

Comment: It never hurts to replace trig functions with $e^{ix}$

Comment: @Hans The integral here is not over the entire real line though.

Comment: @Hans I know about that substitution and I have used that before, but the sine function is not even, so we can not use the semi-circle approach with my function also because the integral is from $0$ to $\infty$ if it is possible, please show me how.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt and RichardClare, you are both right. My bad. I have deleted my false comment. Let use delete the corresponding comments.

Comment: @Hans don't worry and thank you anyway.

Comment: WolframAlpha[1] appears to suggest this integral can't be done.  However, one may note that:

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1+x^2}~\mathrm dx\\&=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{\pi ix}}{(x+i)(x-i)}~\mathrm dx\\&=\frac12\Re\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{\pi ix}}{x+i}-\frac{e^{\pi ix}}{x-i}~\mathrm dx\\&=\dots\end{align}$$


  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%3D0,infinity,sin(x)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2))

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Maybe try placing one leg of the contour on the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: @Hans Yes, a sort of quarter circle contour (or triangle, as the OP mentions) should work from there.

Comment: The integral can be solved in terms of Exponential integral. I don think a contour integration approach is useful here.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: Are you referring to the integrals like $\mathrm{Si}$ just as in Claude Leibovici's answer?

Comment: @Hans, Exponential and Sine,Cosine integrals are closely related.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: I just do not know this name or definition of what you call exponential integral. So your answer to my question is yes?

Comment: @Hans , see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: OK, we agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Without contour integration.*

As Simply Beautiful Art commented, writing

$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1+x^2}=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac i2 \left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x+i}- \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-i}\right)$$ and using 
$$\int \frac{\sin (a x)}{x+b} \,dx=\cos (a b)\, \text{Si}(a(x+ b))-\sin (a b)\, \text{Ci}(a(x+ b))$$ $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (a x)}{x+b} \,dx=\frac{a (2 \text{Ci}(b |a|) \sin (b |a|)+\cos (a b) (\pi -2 \text{Si}(b |a|)))}{2
   |a|}$$ we should end with $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\text{Shi}(\pi ) \cosh (\pi )-\text{Chi}(\pi ) \sinh (\pi )$$ where appear the hyperbolic sine and cosine integral functions.

Comment: Sure, this is essentially the definition of $\mathrm{Si}$ and $\text{Ci}$